# how to read arithmetic data from text file and handle operations in perl

Tags: regex, perl, text-files, arithmetic-expressions

I have a text(example.txt) file which has numbers and arithmetic operations e.g.
`10+5*6`
`8+(4*3)`
`...`
I want to handle these operations and generate output like below in another text file (output.txt)
`10 + 5 * 6 = 40`
`8 + (4 * 3) = 20`
`...`
I'm new to perl, so your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -MSafe -lnE 'say "$_ = ", Safe->new()->reval($_) //"failed"' example.txt
```

[**perldoc Safe**](http://perldoc.perl.org/Safe.html) - Compile and execute code in restricted compartments

Answer (score 0):

This ignores any security concerns

```
perl -ln -e '$a=eval; print "$_ = $a";' < examples.txt
```